# Webcam pictures too bright (with bright bar on top)

Tags: raspbian, usb, webcam, home-automation

Im using a Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000 and when trying to take pictures with both `fswebcam` and `mplayer` the pictures are too bright and/or have a bright bar on the top quarter of the image.

When unplugging the webcam and plugging it back in, i took 3 pictures one after the other; the results were as shown in the images (this is using `fswebcam`):

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Image 3:

[image]

You can sort of see the bright bar on the top quarter of the image.

This shows it better:

[image]

As i used both `fswebcam` and `mplayer` i don't think its to do with the programs but i know that people have used the same webcam with good results so i'm stumped. The only solution at the moment is to unplug and replug but obviously that's not practical.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Skipping 2 frames seems to do the job;
 `fswebcam -r 640x360 -S 2 test.jpg`

I also:

- Update firmware
- Update packages
- Install Streamer; UVCCapture; GUVCView
- Set up permissions and enabled the driver:
  - `sudo usermod -a -G video pi`
  - `sudo modprobe uvcvideo`
- Ensured the webcam was connected before i powered the RPi (if you don't you need to run `sudo rmmod uvcvideo` and `sudo modprobe uvcvideo`